# Determine if a request was via a browser bookmark/favorite vs a link?

Tags: javascript, http, browser, hyperlink, bookmarks

Say I am on a website viewing the homepage at `https://whateverxyz.com/index`.  Then I either

- (A) click a navigation link in the HTML of the page to `https://whateverxyz.com/app1.html`
- (B) click on a browser bookmark to `https://whateverxyz.com/app1.html`

Can the server tell the difference between whether request was from `A` or `B`?  Can client-side JavaScript running on `app1.html` tell the difference?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> **Citate from your question:**
>
> - Can the server tell the difference between whether request was from A or B?
> - Can client-side JavaScript running on app1.html tell the difference?

In both cases this is not possible to detect the difference.

What say us official resources?

> **Citate from** [RFC 7231 - Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.5.2)
>
> *If the target URI was obtained from a source that does not have its own URI (e.g., input from the user keyboard, **or an entry within the
> user's bookmarks/favorites**), the user agent MUST either exclude the
> Referer field or send it with a value of "about:blank".*
>
> *The Referer field has the potential to reveal information about the request context or browsing history of the user, which is a privacy
> concern if the referring resource's identifier reveals personal
> information (such as an account name) or a resource that is supposed
> to be confidential (such as behind a firewall or internal to a secured
> service).  Most general-purpose user agents do not send the Referer
> header field when the referring resource is a local "file" or "data"
> URI.  A user agent MUST NOT send a Referer header field in an
> unsecured HTTP request if the referring page was received with a
> secure protocol.  See [Section
> 9.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-9.4) for additional security considerations.*

**Read more about it:**

- [Referrer Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy)
- [HTTP referer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer)

**Alternative solution**

But something you could do on client side. In the page `https://whateverxyz.com/index` you could write one listener in JavaScript which detect all clicks on this page links. And on click event you could write the *link URL* and the *time* in a `cookie`, an `IndexedDB` or a `localStorage`. Then in the page `https://whateverxyz.com/app1.html` you have to read this information. In the case if this information is not undefined it is from link and in all other cases it is from bookmark (or may be it was tipped in adress bar, or whatever).

**See related questions:**

- [In what cases will HTTP_REFERER be empty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6880659)
- [How to client-side detect when a page is bookmarked?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4776461)
- [How to detect if a link already is in the user's bookmarks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25704556)
- [Is there a way to know if someone has bookmarked your website?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1393618)

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid, you can not find out!
It is only accessible in browsers extensions.

Comment: Do you have proof or documentation?

Comment: @jwl Well, there is no documentation for something that does not exist. Yet, I may refer you to use [WebApplication](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/bookmarks) which works with firefox at least! But I am sure it is not what you have looked for.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a query parameter after the page is loaded with JavaScript. (use `history.pushState` so its not reloading). Like:

`history.pushState({}, "", "?bookmarked")`

So when the navigation is from a bookmark, its with the `?bookmarked` parameter, and when its a regular navigation you'll get it without any parameters.

[Working example](https://js-jcauqr.stackblitz.io/), [Code for example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-jcauqr?file=index.js)

Edit: As pointed out in the comments, there are two problems with this approach.

1. The URL bar in the browser will always include the `?bookmarked` query parameter.
2. When reloading, the server will get the `?bookmarked` even when it's not from the bookmark. (can be worked around as pointed out in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-gets-reloaded-or-refreshed-in-javascript))

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. It is always with `?bookmarked` parameter. May be you have to read about your **[function `history.pushState` in the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)**.

Comment: The example is working fine in for me chrome, however I made an update so that it says on the page if it was loaded from the bookmark.

Comment: It does not work! It is always with ?bookmarked! You should read the documentation.

Comment: Let me explain, the '?bookmarked' will always be there, this is not the way to determine if it's from a bookmark!
The way to check if it's from the bookmark is either by the server checking the URL 'it' received, or by JS checking 'before' adding the '?bookmarked' if there is a '?bookmarked' already.

Please click the example link, you should see "Not From Bookmark", now bookmark it and click on the bookmark, you should now see "From Bookmark" 

BTW: I read the docs multiple times already, please let's try to comply with the stack overflow mission statement.

Comment: It does not work! If you add a bookmark after the page was loaded then the URL is already with '?bookmarked'. I think you misunderstood something.

Comment: That's exactly the point, the 'bookmarked' query is added after the page is loaded so when you bookmark it, it's with the 'bookmarked' query. Now when you load the page from the bookmark, the server gets the request 'with' the 'bookmarked' query. however, if you load the page from a link, even though the query is added its only by JS and the server doesn't get it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178475/discussion-between-mendy-and-bharata).

Comment: That's exactly the point, which you misunderstood! The URL in a link should be the same like in a bookmark! They can not be different!

Comment: Not at all technical explanation, but just visiting the site and refreshing says it's from a bookmark.

Comment: @JackStrosahl, just reading the documentation from this function says _it has nothing to do with checking of bookmarks_.

Comment: Clever technique. Although it's not perfect, it has a high likelihood of differentiating between A and B since most users will bookmark the page they are on rather than bookmarking from a link on a page.