# Determine via Javascript if page load was via a browser bookmark vs clicking on some link?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Say I am on my React app at http://mysite/. Then I either

```
(A) Click to navigate to https://mysite/#/myroute
(B) click on a browser bookmark to https://mysite/#/myroute
```

Can the client-side JavaScript route i.e. MyRoute know whether the navigation was via a browser bookmark vs clicking on some link?

Comment: I think this is solved your problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51826167/determine-if-a-request-was-via-a-browser-bookmark-favorite-vs-a-link

Comment: [`document.referrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer) will be blank when the user came from a bookmark, or the user typed the URL into the box.

Answer (score 1):

> Can the client-side JavaScript route i.e. MyRoute know whether the navigation was via a browser bookmark vs clicking on some link?

If you mean "clicking on some internal link", then yes. But there is no way to distinguish a click on a bookmark from a click on an external link that leads to your website.

In any case, you leverage the [`document.referrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer) property: if it's equal to an empty string, the user navigated from an external source, otherwise it will contain the previous internal url.

Comment: Quite funny that clicking on that very [`document.referrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer) link and inspecting `document.referrer` in the target page it's `""`. Having a referrer might be a proof that the user came from a link, but not having one isn't a proof they came from other means.

Comment: Just tried this inside my React useEffect...even if I navigate from other page, the document.referrer is empty string

Comment: @Kaiido yes that's exactly what I meant in my answer. If I remember well, in a previous version of JavaScript the `referrer` value was always populated with the source page URL. That has been then replaced to an empty string because it infringed on privacy of users

Comment: @copenndthagen I suppose that my answer isn't applicable for SPAs. I'm sorry but I didn't think about it. What about using the session storage?

Comment: @CristianTraìna - you mean using the session storage to push the value on route1 and retrieve on route2...If yes, actually I assume similar can be achieved via passing the route name as props...But I was just trying to see if we can have a more simpler solution..